# Algorithm for flipping a 2d unit space stored in a dictionary vertically

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dictionary, object, mirroring

I have a program that contains objects stored in a 2d unit space.
At certain times, my program will go through this space and remove certain objects, and then replacing them elsewhere. When these objects are placed back in their '*image*' is flipped vertically.

I've provided 2 images below containing the initial view, and then the desired view. Each object is labelled 1 - 7 in the order that they are first removed and put back in.

Initial View:

[image: Initial View]

Desired View:

[image: Desired View]

These objects are stored in a `Dictionary<String, int[2]>` when the key is a unique ID for the object.
As shown in the images, the 1st object goes from a position of `[0, 2]` to `[0, 0]`

I've been thinking about this problem for hours but can't come up with a viable solution.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need an more clarification on this problem, please ask.

Comment: To flip each (x, y) pair, it just gets transformed to `(x, height - y)`, where height is the total height (2 in your example). So `(0, 2)` goes to `(0, 0)`, `(0, 1)` stays at `(0, 1)`, `(0, 0)` goes to `(0, 2)`, and so on

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best. Can't believed I missed this. Thanks